# How to select first row after each 3 rows pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe, i want to get first row of each 3 rows in dataframe and save new dataframe

here is input data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,5,6,7,8,9,9,6]})
```

output:

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,6,9]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with slicing:

```
print (df.iloc[::3])
   x
0  1
3  6
6  9
```

Comment: I don't know why you use `.iloc`? `df[::3]` works too, no?

Comment: @Corralien - ya, but not for columns, more genearal is used for slicing by position `iloc`. But agree, for slice by index in df/series is possible omit `iloc`